# How to run multiple commands on one line when a variable has a space in it

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a program I am working on which would benefit greatly from setting several variables on the same line for the sake of organization. I have it working well enough in some cases, but if a variable in one of the commands is a phrase or sentence, the spaces break it and the program crashes on reaching that line.

Here is how my code is set up:

```
@echo off
set /a roll=(%random%%%100)+1
if %roll% geq 56 set size=Small Town & set shortsize=town
```

The moment the program hits any line like that, it crashes. It will finish if I put quotes around Small Town (or whatever the variable happens to be), but then it will include those quotes in the final output. I do not want that, as I am trying to make human readable text and the phrase small town will be inserted many places into the finished text product.

How can I get the line to run without having quotes visible in the finished .txt file? If the best way is to simply save everything to a text file, then somehow erase every " character from that text file, and *then* open the file for the user to read the results, that will work too.

EDIT:

It may help to see the full table and logic I am working with. SO here it is.

```
:townsize
@echo off
set /a roll=(%random%%%100)+1
if %roll% leq 5 set size=Thorp & set shortsize=thorp
if %roll% geq 6 set size=Hamlet & set shortsize=hamlet
if %roll% geq 11 set size=Village & set shortsize=village
if %roll% geq 56 set size=Small_Town & set shortsize=town
if %roll% geq 66 set size=Medium_Town & set shortsize=town
if %roll% geq 76 set size=Large_Town & set shortsize=town
if %roll% geq 86 set size=Small_City & set shortsize=city
if %roll% geq 96 set size=Medium_City & set shortsize=city
if %roll% equ 99 set size=Large_City & set shortsize=city
if %roll% geq 100 set size=Metropolis & set shortsize=metropolis
if %size% equ Metropolis set /a population=(((%random%%%10)+1)*25000)+125000 & set sizemod=9
if %size% equ Large_City set /a population=(((%random%%%15)+2)*1000)+10000 & set sizemod=8 & set size=Large City"
if %size% equ Medium_City set /a population=(((%random%%%6)+1)*500)+7000 & set sizemod=7 & set size=Medium City"
if %size% equ Small_City set /a population=(((%random%%%6)+1)*500)+5000 & set sizemod=6 & set size=Small City"
if %size% equ Large_Town set /a population=(((%random%%%6)+1)*500)+2000 & set sizemod=5 & set size=Large Town"
if %size% equ Medium_Town set /a population=((%random%%%100)+10)+1000 & set sizemod=4 & set size=Medium Town"
if %size% equ Small_Town set /a population=((%random%%%8)+2)+200 & set sizemod=3 & set size=Small Town"
if %size% equ Village set /a population=((%random%%%8)+2)+200 & set sizemod=2
if %size% equ Hamlet set /a population=((%random%%%20)+2)+50 & set sizemod=1
if %size% equ Thorp set /a population=((%random%%%20)+2) & set sizemod=0
set /a roll=(%random%%%100+1)+%sizemod%
if %roll% geq 100 set popden=55k psm
if %roll% leq 99 if %roll% geq 98 set popden=who are crammed into extreemly close quarters
if %roll% leq 97 if %roll% geq 91 set popden=living in quite the dence urban environment
if %roll% leq 90 if %roll% geq 81 set popden=living in a fairly dence urban environment
if %roll% leq 80 if %roll% geq 21 set popden=with each having enough space to be comfortable
if %roll% leq 20 if %roll% geq 11 set popden=who enjoy fairly spacious yards
if %roll% leq 10 if %roll% geq 4 set popden=who enjoy extreemly spacious dwellings and yards
if %roll% leq 3 if %roll% geq 2 set popden=who deffently prefer their personal space, given the distance between dwellings
if %roll% leq 1 set popden=spread out almost unnaturaly far from one another
goto :eof
```

Comment: `if %roll% geq 56 set "size=Small Town" & set "shortsize=town"`

Comment: This doesn't work. It still crashes. Is there anything else I need to add someplace? Like EnableDelayedExpanshion or something?

Comment: run from an already open command prompt and change `echo off` to `echo on` to see any errormessages.

Comment: @Stephan It works in CMD. But this doesn't run from CMD. It will run from a .bat file.

Comment: I hope that you haven't decided to add your `if` line to the same line as your `set /a`, without enabling and using delayed expansion! Also, to make it easier to read, _(as you have with your `set /a`)_, please use parentheses too, `If %roll% GEq 56 (Set "size=Small Town" & Set "shortsize=town")`.

Comment: @Compo Delayed Expansion doesn't help. Using the () makes it pick the previous result from the table, which can work because it's one word. So that wont' work here.

Comment: @MeeptheChangeling, I didn't ask you to use delayed expansion, I was trying to determine if you were trying to put those two lines together, and it turns out from your response that this is what in fact you're trying to do. Is that correct?

Comment: @Compo Yes. But I split them into 2 lines to make sure it worked at all. The answer is no. It breaks at that space. Which is absurd. I have variables later on that are several sentences of plain text and they work just fine.

Comment: Can I suggest using the method I've described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61105442/12343998) regarding defining outcomes as array indexes in order to avoid so many needless conditional checks;  Just use the random number generated to access the relevent index.

Comment: I am confused if you are using a space or underscore.  Your full code shows an underscore.  Regardless of that, the best practice is to always use quotes for variable assignments: `set "var=small town"`. This does not include the quotes in the variable.  And then when using that variable you should use quotes for the comparison: `IF "%var%"=="small town"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could also do yourself a huge favor, and not mess around with so many If conditions, the way your code is, it's unecessarily time consuming from the perspective of maintainence, and definitely has a readability issue.

As I mentioned in my comment, Indexed variables save alot of headaches.
As an example:

```
:townsize
@echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Create primary Indexed variables
    Set "CitySz[1]=Thorp" & Set "PopDen[1]=spread out almost unnaturaly far from one another"
    Set "CitySz[2]=Hamlet" & Set "PopDen[2]=who enjoy extremely spacious dwellings and yards"
    Set "CitySz[3]=Village" & Set "PopDen[3]=who definitely prefer their personal space, given the distance between dwellings"
    Set "CitySz[4]=Small_Town" & Set "PopDen[4]=who enjoy fairly spacious yards"
    Set "CitySz[5]=Medium_Town" & Set "PopDen[5]=with each having enough space to be comfortable"
    Set "CitySz[6]=Large_Town" & Set "PopDen[6]=living in a fairly dense urban environment"
    Set "CitySz[7]=Small_City" & Set "PopDen[7]=living in quite the dense urban environment"
    Set "CitySz[8]=Medium_City" & Set "PopDen[8]=These folks Ride the train with no elbow room"
    Set "CitySz[9]=Large_City" & Set "PopDen[9]=who are crammed into extremely close quarters"
    Set "CitySz[10]=Metropolis" & Set "PopDen[10]=55k psm"

REM use substring modification to remove unwanted characters from the Town name
REM and assign the modified values to secondary indexed variables
For /L %%A in (1,1,10) do (
    Set "sCitySz[%%A]=!CitySz[%%A]:*_=!"
    Set "dCitySz[%%A]=!CitySz[%%A]:_= !"
    )

REM select the town Index
Set /A "type=%Random% %%10 + 1"

REM Calculate the population of the town
For %%A in (!CitySz[%type%]!) do (
    Set /A randMOD= type + 3
    Set /A randMULT= type * type * type
    Set /A randPLUS= type + 2
    Set Location[%type%]=%%A
    Set "%%A=Set /A population[%type%]= ( ( !random! %%!randMOD! + !randPLUS! ) * !randMULT! ) * type"
    !%%A!
)

REM use the index - type - value to access of the Related variables.
Echo.
Echo.Chosen City:
Echo(!CitySz[%Type%]! / !sCitySz[%Type%]! / !dCitySz[%Type%]! / !population[%Type%]! / !PopDen[%Type%]!
pause
Endlocal & Goto :townsize
```

Comment: The idea of batch files is to automate processes. manually scripting in a pile of variable assignments that can be handled by for loops, along with all the unneccesary conditional checks, is like going out to a restuarant and cooking your own meal. - A bad deal all round.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example line which should perform as you require:

```batch-file
@Set /A "roll=(%random%%%100)+1" & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion & If !roll! GEq 56 (EndLocal & Set "size=Small Town" & Set "shortsize=town") Else EndLocal & Set "size=Big Town" & Set "shortsize=btwn"
```

Obviously you'd adjust the `Else` as required, *(I just made it up)!*

**[Test /]**

```batch-file
@Set /A "roll=(%random%%%100)+1" & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion & If !roll! GEq 56 (EndLocal & Set "size=Small Town" & Set "shortsize=town") Else EndLocal & Set "size=Big Town" & Set "shortsize=btwn"
@Set roll
@Set size
@Set shortsize
@Pause
```

**[Edit /]**
…and just to show you how your recently added, *(via edit)*, more complete script would look:

```batch-file
@Echo Off

:TownSize
Set /A "roll=(%RANDOM% %% 100) + 1"

If %roll% LEq 5 (Set "size=Thorp" & Set "shortsize=thorp" & Set /A "population=((%RANDOM% %% 20) + 2), sizemod=0")
If %roll% GEq 6 (Set "size=Hamlet" & Set "shortsize=hamlet" & Set /A "population=((%RANDOM% %% 20) + 2) + 50, sizemod=1")
If %roll% GEq 11 (Set "size=Village" & Set "shortsize=village" & Set /A "population=((%RANDOM% %% 8) + 2) + 200, sizemod=2")
If %roll% GEq 56 (Set "size=Small Town" & Set "shortsize=town" & Set /A "population=((%RANDOM% %% 8) + 2) + 200, sizemod=3")
If %roll% GEq 66 (Set "size=Medium Town" & Set /A "population=((%RANDOM% %% 100) + 10) + 1000, sizemod=4")
If %roll% GEq 76 (Set "size=Large Town" & Set /A "population=(((%RANDOM% %% 6) + 1) * 500) + 2000, sizemod=5")
If %roll% GEq 86 (Set "size=Small City" & Set "shortsize=city" & Set /A "population=(((%RANDOM% %% 6) + 1) * 500) + 5000, sizemod=6")
If %roll% GEq 96 (Set "size=Medium City" & Set /A "population=(((%RANDOM% %% 6) + 1) * 500) + 7000, sizemod=7")
If %roll% Equ 99 (Set "size=Large City" & Set /A "population=(((%RANDOM% %% 15) + 2) * 1000) + 10000, sizemod=8")
If %roll% Equ 100 (Set "size=Metropolis" & Set "shortsize=metropolis" & Set /A "population=(((%RANDOM% %% 10) + 1) * 25000) + 125000, sizemod=9")

Rem Test the results
(Echo %%roll%%=%roll%, %%size%%=%size%, %%shortsize%%=%shortsize%, %%population%%=%population%, %%sizemod%%=%sizemod% & Pause)

Set /A "roll=((%RANDOM% %% 100) + 1) + sizemod"

If %roll% GEq 100 Set "popden=55k psm"
If %roll% Lss 100 Set "popden=who are crammed into extremely close quarters"
If %roll% Lss 98 Set "popden=living in quite a dense urban environment"
If %roll% Lss 91 Set "popden=living in a fairly dence urban environment"
If %roll% Lss 81 Set "popden=with each having enough space to be comfortable"
If %roll% Lss 21 Set "popden=who enjoy fairly spacious yards"
If %roll% Lss 11 Set "popden=who enjoy extremely spacious dwellings and yards"
If %roll% Lss 3 Set "popden=who definitely prefer their personal space, given the distance between dwellings"
If %roll% Equ 1 Set "popden=spread out almost unnaturaly far from one another"

Rem Test the results
(Echo %%roll%%=%roll%, %%popden%%=%popden% & Pause)

GoTo :EOF
```

Please remember, when testing, to only test exactly what I have provided. Anything added or modified outside of this code, does not form part of my answer.

Comment: Nope, still crashes instantly on execution (though I did force the line to make roll =57 so I could test that line and not the rest of the table of possibilities.

Comment: It doesn't, perhaps you didn't ask it to remain open! Please create a batch-file, _(that is a plain text file with  a `.cmd` extension)_, and copy the **[Test /]** version code and run it. If it crashes, I'll eat my hat!

Comment: …what, no quick comment? Don't be embarassed to have been wrong, you came here for assistance from somebody more knowledgeable than you, and got it. The problem now is realising that you're going to have to fix a lot more of your own script, or you have come to the realization that one line per command doesn't take longer to run, and with indentation and parenthesized blocks is much easier to read and maintain.

Comment: No quick comment because I don't get any notifications for this and became too frustrated to hit F5. It dosn't work as a .cmd either. Good thought though. I was using .bat It also dosnt' work if I unnest the commands either. I'm at a total loss.

Comment: I haven't been embarrassed to be wrong since I was like 8. If I seem childishly angry, it is because I am autistic and the official instructions on how to do this do not work.

Comment: It works 100% every time, @MeeptheChangeling, _(now tested on some of my repair units, [tag:windows-xp], [tag:windows-vista], [tag:windows-7] and [tag:windows-10])_. If it isn't working then your PC has issues outside of the question.

Comment: @MeeptheChangeling, out of courtesy, I have also rewritten your additional "full table and logic", as an edit to the answer above. It has also been tested, _(on the same units mentioned in my previous comment)_, and has, in every case, worked flawlessly.